# Correspondence theorem for the localization of graded ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $S_\cdot$ be a graded ring, take localization at some element $f\in S_+$ (where $S_+$ is the irrelevant ideal, and  $f$ is a homogenous elements, therefore $S_f$ has the natural graded ring structure).  The standard correspondence theorem tell us that $$\{\text{prime ideals of $S_f$}\} \Longleftrightarrow \{\text{prime ideals of S do not containing $f$}\}$$

via contraction and extension.

---

Can we upgrad this correspondence to the homogenous prime ideal? that is
$$\{\text{homogenous prime ideals of $S_f$}\} \Longleftrightarrow \{\text{homogemous prime ideals of S that do not containing $f$ and $S_+$}\}$$

There is something to do [homogenous prime ideal can contains $S_+$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2106905/360262) .

Comment: You probably want $f$ to be homogeneous here, not just in the irrelevant ideal. (What's your motivation for this question?)

Comment: I was reading Vakil's FOAG, he asked me to interpret the $\left(\left(S_{\bullet}\right)_f\right)_0$ as subset of $\text{Proj} S_\bullet$ in exercise 4.5H, just like what we did in the affine case. It seems the correspondence is not very hard to prove, I will try to work it out later.

Comment: Remember, [source and motivation goes in the question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/29298#29298).

Comment: Thank you for your help, KReiser I will try to post question with better quality.

Comment: @yi li - You may be aware of this: The homogeneous coordinate ring $S$ is not an invariant for $X:=Proj(S)$. There are $S,T$ with $S \neq T$ but $Proj(S) \cong Proj(T)$. Hence the projective scheme $X:=Proj(S)$ is best studied using an open cover $U_i$ of affine schemes $U_i$. You "seldom" study $X$ using homogeneous ideals in $S$.

Comment: @yi li - for affine schemes $X_i:=Spec(A_i)$ it follows $X_1 \cong X_2$ are isomorphic schemes iff $A_1 \cong A_2$ are isomorphic rings, but this does not hold for $Proj(-)$. You may find many threads on this site where they study the question when two graded  $S$-modules $M,N$ define the same sheaf on $X:=Proj(S)$. It may be that $M \neq N$ but the corresponding sheaf on $X$ are isomorphic. For this reason one usually studies $Proj(S)$ in terms of an open affine cover and glueing - one defines morphisms locally and glues etc.

Comment: @yi li - as an example: The 2-uple embedding $C:=\mathbb{P}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^2:=S$ is a closed immersion onto the closed subscheme $Z:=V(xz-y^2) \subseteq S$, but to prove this one covers $Z$ with 3 open subschemes and constructs an inverse locally and glue this to a global map $Z \rightarrow C$.

Comment: @hm2020  , thank you for your help hm2020 (I was going to sleep last night therefore didn't see the message),  I always learn a lot from you, thank you! that's a very interesting remark that I haven't learned from the book.

Comment: very thanks hm2020 !